# How to optimize the following subroutine?

Tags: performance, perl, optimization, hash, reference

Here's the subroutine I'm trying to optimize. It utilizes array references for the most part. Currently this subroutine takes approx. 30-40 seconds to run on average. I would like to reduce this to 10 seconds if possible. Do you see anything unnecessary that pops out to you?

```
sub compute{
    # takes two params: 2 array_refs
    my ($gene_exp_ref, $centroids_ref) = @_;
    my ($numerator, $denominator) = 0;

    my ($prod_ref, $diff_x_ref, $diff_y_ref, $x_sq_ref, $y_sq_ref) = [];  # diff_y is the center_gene
    my %gene_center_pcc;                   # diff_x is gene of interest

    my $gene_exp_average = mean($gene_exp_ref);

    for my $gene_exp (@{$gene_exp_ref}) {
        push(@{ $diff_x_ref }, ($gene_exp - $gene_exp_average));
    }

    # possible bottleneck
    for my $centroid_gene_exp_ref (values %{$centroids_ref}){
        $diff_y_ref = [];  # initilize back to empty array
        for my $index (@{$centroid_gene_exp_ref}) {
            push(@{ $diff_y_ref }, ($index - mean($centroid_gene_exp_ref)));
        }

        @{ $prod_ref } = map { @{ $diff_x_ref }[$_] * @{ $diff_y_ref }[$_] } 0..$#{ $diff_x_ref };

        $numerator = sum($prod_ref);

        @{ $x_sq_ref } = map {$_*$_}@$diff_x_ref;
        @{ $y_sq_ref } = map {$_*$_}@$diff_y_ref;

        $denominator = sqrt(sum($x_sq_ref)) * sqrt(sum($y_sq_ref));

        my $r = $numerator/$denominator;

        my ($center) = grep { @{$gene_centers{$_}} ~~ @$centroid_gene_exp_ref } keys %gene_centers;
        $gene_center_pcc{$center} = $r;
    }

#return the center with the highest PCC
return (sort {$gene_center_pcc{$b} <=> $gene_center_pcc{$a}}
    keys %gene_center_pcc)[0];
}
```

Each calculation and number crunching step is necessary. It compiles but you won't be able to use the subroutine properly unless you have the data file.

Comment: Code?  Hard to answer this question without the code.

Comment: Why did you edit the question to remove the code completely? Being able to look at the original code is an important part of seeing the value of the optimisations recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for my $index (@{$centroid_gene_exp_ref}) {
    push(@{ $diff_y_ref }, ($index - mean($centroid_gene_exp_ref)));
}
```

This will recalculate the mean for every item in `@{$centroid_gene_exp_ref}`.  If that array is large, it will add up exponentially (I'm assuming that `mean()` doesn't cache or memoize the result, forcing it to loop over the array each time it's called).  You may be able to save a fair amount of time by caching the mean yourself:

```
my $mean = mean($centroid_gene_exp_ref);
for my $index (@{$centroid_gene_exp_ref}) {
    push(@{ $diff_y_ref }, ($index - $mean));
}
```

Beyond that, check with [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf) to find your actual bottleneck(s) and target optimizations at those points.

Comment: excellent! thank you, that brought the runtime down to approx. 5- 12 seconds. :-) Is there anything else you see?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look at the bigger picture, taking into account your previous post in which you show that you call `compute()` for every key in `%$centroids_ref`:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %HoA ) {
    compute($HoA{$key}, \%HoA);  # on the first iteration, this actually passes an aref to [1,3,3,3]
}
```

Even after Dave Sherohman's optimisation, you're still doing a whole lot of calculations (like `mean`) over and over again.

My suggestion is that you bring the outer loop into `compute()`. Then for each key in the HoA you can store your calculations and reuse those values for each key.

```
sub compute{
    my ($centroids_ref) = @_;

    # precalculate these values once
    my %means;
    my %diffs;
    my %sqrts;
    foreach my $key (keys %$centroids_ref) {
        my $mean = mean($centroids_ref->{$key});
        my @diffs = map {$_ - $mean} @{$centroids_ref->{$key}};

        my @squares = map {$_ * $_} @diffs;
        my $sqrt = sqrt(sum(\@squares));

        $means{$key} = $mean;
        $diffs{$key} = \@diffs;
        $sqrts{$key} = $sqrt;
    }

    # now do the main calculations from the 'possible bottlenecks' section
    ...
}
```

Comment: @steveni thanks for the suggestion! I will try that out. can you remove the subroutine you posted above? it's not ready to be open-source just yet :0

Comment: thanks a lot. will do! I will implement this in later today then get back to you.

Comment: I'm getting times between approx. 16-25 seconds and it's not doing what's originally intended. The original subroutine I posted took in two array_refs as params but in your solution you're only using the second array_ref passed in.

Comment: Yes the subroutine has changed. It means you no longer need to call it from within a loop because the loop is now inside it. (I just realised that my version of the return statement has a bug and should return a hash of values rather than a single value.)